# Using multiple PHP files while avoiding redirect loop and resubmission

Tags: php

So I am pretty new to PHP, I have done and learnt lots of console based experience so I'm not a full beginner to programming. But I decided to learn how to database because its always fascinated me, and I've learnt the basic HTML and CSS and JS, and now basic PHP and SQL, but putting into action is getting weird on me.

I've figured out how to manipulate and make databases through PHP code and stuff like that, but they were all simple things and in one file, I am going for a bigger project and I need to put all the PHP's in separate files, this is the problem.

say my 'index.php' file is so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include 'other.php' ?>    //Problem 1
    </head>
    <body>
        <FORM method="POST" action="other.php">
            <INPUT type="text" name="textTest" value="<?php print $input; ?>">
            <INPUT type="submit" name="subTest" value="TEST" >
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my 'other.php' is :

```
<?php

$input = "";

if (isset ($_POST['subTest']))
{
    $input = $_POST['textTest'];

    //header("Location : index.php");
}

header("Location: index.php");   //Problem 2

?>
```

so my problems:

- Problem 1, if I don't include the 'other.php' file, there is an error when I try print the: value = "print $input"
- Problem 2, if I don't redirect with 'header', it obviously doesn't redirect and go back to the 'index.php' which I want to happen. BUT with it there, it causes a TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error. I found this is a problem caused by the include which can't be removed for Problem 1 reasons.
- Problem 3, I found out I could move the 'header' function to where it is commented out, but then the value="..." doesn't stay on submit.
- Problem 4, if I completely get rid of the 'header' redirect, and change the form's action to 'index.php', then I get the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' thing I want to avoid.

So I hope that is a mouthful someone understands and can help with, and thankyou in advanced.

Comment: Try to not mix the logic (if isset(blah, blah, blah) then redirect) with output (HTML). Reorganize your files and do all the required processing and take all the needed decisions **before** any output. Don't include files that process data from files that output HTML; do it the other way around.

Comment: After basic try learning simple design pattern like MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` does what it sounds like, it includes the file into the parent, essentially the same as copy and pasting the content into it.

So to fix your problem, 1st change the forms action to `index.php` (so it posts to its self), and remove the redirect all together:

```
<?php include 'other.php' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <FORM method="POST" action="index.php">
            <INPUT type="text" name="textTest" value="<?php print $input; ?>">
            <INPUT type="submit" name="subTest" value="TEST" >
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

other.php:

```
<?php    
$input = "";

if (isset ($_POST['subTest'])){

    $input = $_POST['textTest'];
}
```

Note that i also moved the `include` to the 1st line in `index.php`, before any html output.
This is not strictly required in this instance, but is a good practice, as you are unable to set headers (eg for a redirect) after the response body is sent to the output stream

EDIT
If you want to avoid form resubmits on refresh, then you are correct that you would need to submit to a seperate endpoint and redirect.
To do that you would need to pass the posted data back to the index file, as the redirect is a new (GET) request, so the post data is lost.

The two main ways to do that would be with SESSION or URL parameters.
I'll show how to do it with parameters:

Dont include the destination file:

```
<?php
//get value from url parameter, or set to empty string if parameter not present
$input = isset($_GET['input'])? $_GET['input'] : '';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <FORM method="POST" action="other.php">
            <INPUT type="text" name="textTest" value="<?php print $input; ?>">
            <INPUT type="submit" name="subTest" value="TEST" >
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then append the required data to the redirect url as parameters
other.php:

```
<?php    
$input = "";

if (isset ($_POST['subTest'])){

    $input = $_POST['textTest'];
    header("Location: index.php?" . http_build_query(['input'=>$input]));
    die(); //always stop execution after redirect
}
//if post data not sent, something went wrong, so set $input parameter to error message
header("Location: index.php?" . http_build_query(['input'=>'No Data posted']));
die(); //always stop execution after redirect
```

Comment: That is what causes Problem 4, on refresh, I get the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' and everywhere I have looked says to solve that, add a 'header' redirect in, so how do I do both?

Comment: I like that practice, but it still comes up with Resubmission thing

Comment: Ok, i made the edit showing how to use a redirect to avoid form re-submissions

Comment: Wow, okay I am only a beginner so that is a bit for me to understand (I'll get there haha), and it doesn't like the 'input'=>, says => is unexpected?

But still thankyou for helping!

Comment: Oops, `http_build_query` expects an array, i missed the square brackets that denote an array, added them now.

Comment: I've got a bit to learn now haha but thankyou for all the help, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

In other.php at the last line try require-ing the index.php instead of redirrecting. 
Also remove the inclusion of other.php in index.php .

```
$input = "";

if (isset ($_POST['subTest']))
{
    $input = $_POST['textTest'];
}

require_once 'index.php';
?>
```

Comment: If I don't include 'other.php' in 'index.php', the value="..." will throw a error, it doesn't know what $input is

Comment: No it won't. If you require index.php from other.php than index.php has access to the scope of other.php. In other words it can access it's variables.